# Webpack 4 + Babel leaving const in transpiled code

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-4

I'm trying to get my code working on Android 4.1 Webview, which doesn't support ES6.

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

**.babelrc config**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "lodash"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "android": "4.1"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "forceAllTransforms": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-stage-0"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: ['lodash']
        },
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
   ]
```

Comment: If you look at the output bundle, is the `const` from your own code, or something in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out, that the issue was caused by the "query-string" module, which is a dependency of another package.
As described on GitHub, I've installed version 5 explicitly. Then everything worked well.

[Github: query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string)

> This module targets Node.js 6 or later and the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. If you want support for older browsers, use version 5: npm install query-string@5.

Comment: Same issue happened to me, it was both query-string and  the package object-assign-deep that messed up the built bundle, because object-assign-deep was not intended for browser use. and query-string 6 is not supporting older browsers like IE 11.