# identify dependencies that stop babel from transpiling into vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Babel is leaving const in my transpiled bundle. Following is how the relevant parts of my webpack.config.js looks like -

```
target: "web",
mode: "development",
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\/.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: [
            'env'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In one of the other StackOverflow [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508675/webpack-4-babel-leaving-const-in-transpiled-code), 'query-string' version targeting Node.js 6 was mentioned as one of the problematic dependencies.

How can I identify dependencies which make `Babel` leave const in transpiled code? Is there a way to make Babel give some warning(s) before it decides to failover to higher javascript version.

Note: I am using `Webpack 4`.